# Update Mongodb and keep databases

Tags: mongodb, auto-update

It is possible to update mongodb (Currently in version 2.0.6 and I need > 2.2) and keep databases ?
Mongodb running on Debian 7

Comment: Updating MongoDB is an administrative task, not a task for a software developer. As such it is better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com. I nominated your question for migration. You can accelerate this by deleting your question here and reposting it on https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

> MongoDB 2.0 data files are compatible with 2.2-series binaries without
>   any special migration process. However, always perform the upgrade
>   process for replica sets and sharded clusters using the procedures
>   that follow.

As said on the mongodb release notes. Also when your making an upgrade, since your current version is **2.0.6** you need to upgrade to **2.2** first.

If you want to go up to the latest version you have to keep upgrading version one by one as said on the release notes [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/).

**Upgrading a Standalone version**

1. Download binaries of the latest release in the 2.2 series from the MongoDB [Download Page](http://downloads.mongodb.org/?_ga=1.91873240.393739143.1447240597).
2. Shutdown your [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instance. Replace the existing binary with the 2.2 [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) binary and restart MongoDB.